# running web2py with GoogleAppEngineLauncher

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

Trying to run my web2py app from the development server using GoogleAppEngineLauncher

Not sure if the on-line tutorials are out of date or I'm just missing something, but when I follow the link to download the GoogleAppEngine pythonSDK for OSX I get a dmg for the GoogleAppEngineLauncher.

I download and use that, which installs the proper executables, however after I setup my app.yaml file and run "dev_appserver.py myApp" I get this error:

fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException: Host appengine.google.com returned an invalid certificate (_ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed):

I don't get the error if I try and launch the app from the launcher itself, however I can't launch the app because it says the directory already exists and I don't have write permissions.  I even tried chmod 777 on the myApp directory.

Should I not be using the GoogleAppLauncher?

additionally I tried using the linux SDX and received the same "certificate" error.  The error message directs me to a [link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#rpcssl) mentioning that I need the "ssl" module, but that is included in python 2.7.2 which I am using.

The link also mentions: "appcfg uses SSL when connecting to the Admin Console by default, unless the --insecure flag is passed."  But I cannot find that flag in the help menu.

Answer (score 1):

Found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899530/gae-sdk-1-7-4-and-invalidcertificateexception) which solves the problem.

Basically:

```
rm google_appengine/lib/cacerts/cacerts.txt
```

From the SDK