# GAE can't generate discovery file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I upgraded my GAE SDK to Version 1.8.5 and cannot generate a discovery file anymore with endpointscfg.py gen_discovery_doc -o.-f rpc .../main.FlyFlap.APi

I get the errors below.

I tried to delete the file google_appengine/lib/cacerts/urlfetch_cacerts.txt and certs.txt  like it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899530/gae-sdk-1-7-4-and-invalidcertificateexception), but it didn't help. Does someone got same problems?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/endpointscfg.py", line 196, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/endpointscfg.py", line 192, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 472, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 467, in main
    args.callback(args)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 348, in _GenDiscoveryDocCallback
    output_path, hostname=hostname)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 188, in GenDiscoveryDoc
    service_configs = GenApiConfig(service_class_names, hostname=hostname)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/endpointscfg.py", line 144, in GenApiConfig
    module_name, base_service_class_name = service_class_name.rsplit('.', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: I updated my iMac to OSX 10.8.5 and tadaaa it works again..

Comment: Why don't you close the question then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated osx and it works again.