# Deploying Static Website via Google App Engine app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, web-deployment

I've been trying to deploy my website using Google App Engine. I have a domain name. I have a bucket with all my files uploaded into it, organized the way that google wants them. I even have the app.yaml file in the folder. However, every time I try to deploy the app I get this message:

[image: picture of the message]

Any advice?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid posting text as images, instead copy-paste it into the answer (and format it accordingly).

Comment: `organized the way that google wants them` - the error message contradicts that - otherwise everything would be working as expected :) So I'd suggest adding details, starting with your `app.yaml` file. And maybe pointers to the doc you're using - so that we can get an idea about how are you trying to do things. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Try passing the `app.yaml` file explicitly to `gcloud app deploy` - it's not that good at figuring things out all by itself in every situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error represent a problem with the app.yaml file. here you can see an example of the app.yaml file for static sites-structure.

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*)
```

Also you can follow these official [recommendations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website)

*Off course, is necessary validate gcloud to use the last version updated.

```
gcloud components update
```

If you receive problems with the SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899530/gae-sdk-1-7-4-and-invalidcertificateexception) because maybe is a problem with SDK but depend the OS and other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `gcloud init` first? You need to do so first and follow instructions to create a named gcloud configuration e.g `my_ga_app`.

And then every time before running deploy, you need to run (only necessary if you are working on multiple apps):

`gcloud config configurations activate my_ga_app`

then the deploy

`gcloud app deploy`

if this does not work, make sure your gcloud is upto date by running

`gcloud components update`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately neither worked :( I was able to initialize my configuration, but it still gave me the same error message about not recognizing the app.yaml file. I tried to update my gcloud but then got an error message saying "ERROR: gcloud crashed (SSLHandshakeError): [Errno 1] _ssl.c:499: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed". When I tried to run diagnostics, the diagnostic test also failed. I don't know what any of this means or where this leaves me. But thanks for your time anyway!